# How can I skip the updated_at field when adding a nested object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have following line:

```
puts @post.updated_at # -> 2014-11-01 09:34:13

@comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params.merge(user: current_user))
@comment.save

puts @post.updated_at # -> 2014-11-01 09:43:01
```

Which obviously adds a comment to the given post but also updates the `updated_at` column in my @post object. Is there any elegant way to skip that?

Thanks

UPDATE:

All I can think of now is this:

```
updated_at = @post.updated_at
@comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params.merge(user: current_user))
@comment.save
@post.update_column('updated_at', updated_at)
```

Which I don't think is very nice.

Comment: No.. There is nothing. `updated_at` column is there for that purpose only.

Comment: Well, I know there's ways to keep updated_at, I just want to know an elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that no callbacks in `Comment` model, cause this update.

If you don't build through the @post object, it won't be touched.

```
@comment = Comment.create(comment_params.merge(user: current_user, post: @post))
```